# Irreducible polynomials over $\mathbb{Z}_p$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

Let odd prime $p$ be given. Is there a way to determine the:

(1) number of irreducible polynomials $x^2+bx+1$ over $\mathbb{Z}_p$?

(2) possible values of $b$ for which $x^2+bx+1$ over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is irreducible?

Thank you so much!

Comment: What answers do you get for $p\le 20$ say?

Comment: I only ask because I think the answer to (i) is $\frac{1}{2}(p-1)$.

Comment: I don't think there is a very simple and concise answer to (2). For instance, $b = 0$ makes $x^2+bx+1$ irreducible iff $p$ is congruent to $3$ modulo $4$. I suspect that that's the _easiest_ $b$ to describe, and describing the entire collection of $b$'s for an arbitrary $p$ is going to be very tricky.

Comment: Well @Arthur they've got to be those $\alpha+\alpha^{-1}$ as $\alpha$ runs through the cyclic subgroup of order $p+1$ in $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}^{*}$ (excluding the element of order $2$).

Comment: @ancientmathematician My first thought was that it's the numbers that are _not_ of the form $-\alpha-\alpha^{-1}$ as $\alpha$ runs through the elements of $\Bbb Z_p$. But still, that observation doesn't make it much easier to answer a question like "Is $b = 392$ valid for $p = 673$?"

Comment: You're probably right @Arthur. Someone might crunch a few examples to provide a bit of evidence.